# asp.net mvc display different content depending on condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I have 2 different types of data to display (for instance users and products). Depending on condition I need to display users or products. I heard that the best practice says that we need to introduce extension method whenever we want to add if to View. But user and product html seems too complex to hardcode into extension method. Is there any kind of best practice to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive decided to use [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/03/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-2.aspx) solution (#18 html helper extensions). Will combine it with [this](http://thecodeslinger.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/expression-based-renderaction-htmlhelper-extension/) extension method. It will allow to write things like this html.RenderMyPageData(Model);
If would be incapsulated inside the method. And it will not generate html with string builder, but will use ready to work partial views.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the concern of having `if`s in the view would be this might introduce business logic (which has no place in the presentation layer).

Is your use of `if` concerned purely with presentation? Then use it in the view.

Is the `if` implementing some business logic? Reconsider your design.

If you still go with having an `if` in the view (and without knowing more about your project), I'm not sure why you would need to use an extension method. I don't see any problem with something similar to:

```
<%
    if (someCondition)
    {   
        Html.RenderAction("User", "Index");
    } 
    else
    {   
        Html.RenderAction("Product", "Index");
    }    
%>
```

Comment: Graham, sure this is one of the ways to go. But seems very awkward, isn`t it? If I have 5 similiar things to display I will have spaghetti code. That`s why instead of using if it`s recommended to make and extension method. You`ll use it like Html.MySpecialMarkup(Model)

Answer (score 0):

Using an if stmt really isn't spaghetti as you aren't going back and forth between code. Its also fairly readable. Using an extension method in this case you wouldnt be hard coding any html, but simply again redirecting to the particular action to return, so its a question of either having the same code in your view - or the logic for the view processed in your extension method.